# change String to datetime from an input file

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an input file which contains datetime. My purpose is to read the file and filter the db.

Input file sample

```
2019-05-31 15:21:53
```

Below code work fine in my PC (python 3.6.4)

```
f=open("lastRun.txt", "r+")
lastHour=(f.read())
f.close()

lHourDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastHour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(lHourDate)
```

however in production we have (Pyhton 3.6.7)
where the same code is throwing below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hourlyLoadEscenic.py", line 37, in <module>
    lHourDate = datetime.strptime(lastHour, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

I can do 'print' and see the lastHour has the input field. but in date conversion it is throwing error.

Please suggest

Comment: unconverted data remains appears blank, maybe try strip any unprintable characters `lastHour = f.read().strip()`?

Comment: 1) Please post the rest of the error. 2) Are you sure the file in production only contains one line and its the date? You are doing a `read` not `readline` so you are attempting to cast the entire file to that date template

Comment: @davedwards thank you for the solution.. put strip() and boom it worked

Comment: great, glad it helped